# Using nth-child(odd) does not seem to behave as I would expect

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a piece of CSS like so:

```
.formTable:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: #eeb;
}
```

I also have a form with the following basic structure (obviously not the complete HTML).  Of note is the `dynTable1` that is loaded with an AJAX call in certain circumstances.

```
<table class="formTable" id="table1" />
<table class="formTable" id="table2" />
<table class="formTable" id="table3" />
<table class="formTable" id="table4" />
<div id="divDynamic1" class="fadeIn">
    <table class="formTable" id="dynTable1" />
</div>
```

the thing that doesn't make sense to me is, the `nth-child` selector will key against `table2`, `table4` and `dynTable1` on Firefox and IE9 (I did not try others).  I would have expected `dynTable1` to not have the style applied to it.  Clearly my understanding of how `nth-child` works is lacking, but while my Google-fu uncovered many examples of how to use `nth-child`, I had difficulty finding a simple explanation of how it worked in this sort of case.  So, I turn to SO.

Why does `nth-child` behave like this, and how can I make it alternate strictly between `table` elements of class `formTable`?

Comment: Why would that be?  And that does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: Yeah, there's no difference between `2n-1` and `odd`. They're identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:nth-child(odd)` is applied to elements that are 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc children *of their own parent container*, not their children. I'm guessing there are some other elements before the `.formTable`s in their parent container? That's why every second table matches the rule, and `#dynTable1` matches because it is the 1st child of `#divDynamic1`.

**EDIT:** Now that I understand what you're trying to achieve, I can suggest something like this:

```
.wrapper > div > .formTable
{
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) > .formTable:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: #eeb;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(even) > .formTable:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: #eeb;
}
​
```

What it does is reset the background color of the tables inside the `div`s, then specifies new alternation rules for the tables inside them - starting from gray if the `div` is an even child, and yellow if it is an odd child.

Comment: So how would I get the desired effect of alternating the backgrounds of the tables?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: It depends on whether you want to alternate the backgrounds of the dynamic tables inside `div`s as well. If not, see Per's answer. If yes, you'll need some more complex rules to keep the alternation in sync inside the `div`.

Comment: How complex are we talking about?  I would like all `.formTable` elements displayed on the screen to alternate in background color, regardless of the div structure they are nested in.  I had assumed that would be simple; it seems less likely now...

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Not overly complex, you'll just have to specify separate rules for the alternations for cases when the `div` is an odd child, and when it is an even one. See this updated fiddle I hijacked from Per: http://jsfiddle.net/4SYzu/1/

Comment: That is complex, but it seems to work quite well.  I will have to chew on this to understand what is going on here, but this does indeed seem to be the answer I was looking for.  Let me ask this: should I have used `nth-of-type()` instead?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: You can avoid the problem presented in Per's example by making sure your dynamic tables are always the last ones in the list.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja, that may be the strategy I take; still, it seems crazy that there is not a simple way of defining a style to apply to every other element of the same class in the DOM.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: I've never needed a selector like that myself, but this is clearly a use case where it would be useful. You could also consider removing the `#divDynamic1` and just appending the new dynamically loaded elements after the preloaded ones, if possible.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja, I like to have anchors for my AJAX loads if possible.  Thanks, you helped me come up with a workable solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are targeting all `.formTable`. Even the ones in `#divDynamic1`. (and `odd` targets the first, third, fifth e.t.c elements, which is why the first table in `#divDynamic1` is targeted)

Try using a wrapper to specify that you only want to target children:

```
.wrapper > .formTable:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: #eeb;
}​
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4SYzu/) for you.

Comment: This is the result I already have, and am trying to work around.

Comment: Really? In my fiddle `#dynTable1` is **not** colored. What browser are you using?

Comment: Oh. Ok, after reading some comments I see what you want to do.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought the color pattern was reversed; this is the exact opposite of what I have, but still not what I'm looking for.  I guess I didn't explain well, but I want all `.formTable` elements, regardless of their placement in the DOM, to display on the screen in alternating background colors.